# Solr Highlighting not working without hl.q

Tags: solr, highlighting, solr6

I am using `Solr 6.0`. I want to use the `Highlighting` feature of `Solr`.

When I make the following query the `highlighting` section in the response has only ids (without `&hl.q=data:*ad*`) -

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/solr/<core>/select?q=text:ad&fl=data&rows=10&hl=on&hl.fl=data&hl.preserveMulti=true&hl.mergeContiguous=true
```

Output -

```
"highlighting": {
    "id1": {},
    "id2": {}
}
```

When I make the following query then I get the desired output (with `&hl.q=data:*ad*`) -

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/solr/<core>/select?q=text:ad&fl=data&rows=10&hl=on&hl.q=data:*ad*&hl.fl=data&hl.preserveMulti=true&hl.mergeContiguous=true
```

Output -

```
"highlighting": {
    "id1": {
        "data": ["<em>advertise</em>",
            "<em>add</em>"
        ]
    },
    "id2": {
        "data": ["<em>admin</em>",
            "<em>addon</em>"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Why do I need to pass hl.q? Is there a way to avoid it?**

If I want to write a custom `requestHandler` `(qt)` in `solrconfig.xml` then can I pass the q value to `hl.q` with `*` as prefix and postfix something like `hl.q=*$q*`.

I have the following 2 fields -

```
<field name="text" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="data" type="lower" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Following is the definition of the fields -

```
<fieldType name="lower" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="30"/>
         <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Following is the way data is copied in the 2 fields -

```
<copyField source="somefield" dest="text" maxChars="30"/>
<copyField source="somefield" dest="data"/>
```

**EDIT 1**

When I add `&hl.alternateField=data` to the first query then all values in the multi-valued fields show up in the `highlighting` section just like a normal search. Like below -

```
"highlighting": {
    "id1": {
        "data": ["advertise",
            "not relevant",
            "add"
        ]
    },
    "id2": {
        "data": ["admin",
            "addon",
            "irrelevant"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the EdgeNGram filter to the *lower* type and it will match the first example. It won't match "ad" in data because it doesn't have any NGrams.